# Unable to test in app purchase with delphi firemonkey iOS app

Tags: ios, delphi, testing, in-app-purchase, firemonkey

So I used the delphi wiki to set up in app purchases in my application. My app is set up properly in iTunes connect (actually already has one release, before I decided to add an in app purchase).

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_the_iOS_In-App_Purchase_Service

However, the status of my in app purchase is currently "Ready To submit" from doing googling, apparently i -should- be able to test the in app purchase while it's in this state by using a sandbox apple account. Which I have setup.

However, the way everyone says to sign into the account is by launching the app and attempting the purchase (hitting a button that calls the in app purchases components "PurchaseProduct" procedure), which should then prompt me to login. But I never get the prompt.

I believe this is because the product I created is not being found by the application, as when I use the "queryProducts" procedure on the in app purchases product. it comes back and says that my productID was invalid. But I know it is valid, the product ID in appstore connect is "ProMode" and my product IDs string list is populated with one entry "ProMode". I am also using the correct ID when I try the purchaseProduct call of "ProMode"

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here, if someone could provide me with some insight. that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you aren't able to fetch your products and they're in the "Ready To Submit" stage, make sure you have your "Paid Applications Agreement" signed in App Store Connect. Here's a nice post outlining common errors that prevent products from being fetched: [Configuring In-app Products is Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard)

Also, on iOS 12, you can set a default sandbox user in `Settings -> Your Account -> iTunes & App Store -> Sandbox Account`. This can help out with the sign in prompts.